# Word Document.Close and Thread Abort Exception Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

I have a project type office 2010 word document.

In ribbon there is a button which does some logic.
On the end of this logic there is a line like:

```
Globals.ThisDocument.Application.ActiveDocument.Close(ref dowdSaveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

On Windows XP everything worked ok but when a user tries to work with this document on Windows 7 this line of code throws exception like:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: The thread was beeing aborted. 
   w Document35.WorkflowRibbon.Button1Click(Object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) w D:\_DEV\WorkflowCS2_WordTemplatest_Office2010\Document35\WorkflowRibbon.cs:wiersz
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue of the AppDomain unloading and returning execution from unmanaged to managed code. [See MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/ccf48a36-97f0-4f4c-839d-73aaa3f2bf95/) which discusses this `ThreadAbortExcpetion` behavior. Potentially you just need to update the VSTO Runtime.

Comment: I have VS 2010 with VSTO 4.0. How can I check my VSTO runtime version and if needed update it?

Comment: How are you deploying the Add-In? Typically this is done during installation.

Comment: This is not an add-in. This is Word Document 2010 project. In VS I see something like that Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.v9.0.dll runtime v2.0.50727

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    private void Button1Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object dowdSaveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
        try
        {                
             Globals.ThisDocument.Application.ActiveDocument.Close(ref dowdSaveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);                
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException t)
        {
            Globals.ThisDocument.ThisApplication.Quit(ref dowdSaveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: nope, it won't work. We decided not to close our application but only the document. User has to close word manually.